# What would ancient warfare look like with basic radios & railways?

Tags: warfare, ancient-history, radio, trains

What would ancient warfare look like with basic radios & railways? The other changes are easy access to steel & very basic steam engines. Everything else technology wise is the same as the ancient era around the time of Caesar. How would ancient warfare be affected by the fast movement of information, supplies, & men?

Comment: How are those resources accessible to the multiple parties of the conflict? Logistics is almost always the decisive factor in most conflicts - hence why having access to logistics breakthroughs (Roman roads, railroads in American Civil War...) is very important

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza i haven't figured that out yet

Comment: What do the governments in this war look like? With all these transportation and communication technologies, I imagine they're quite a bit more centralized than they would be in reality.

Comment: *"Everything technology wise is the same as the ancient era around the time of Caesar"*, but they have radios, railways, steel and aluminium... Sorry, that's not possible. A world with railways is in **no way** similar to the world in which C. Julius Caesar lived. For starters, it has waaaaay too many people with a good education, a stable job and a stable income. (Those railways do not run themselves -- they need a large army of engineers, mechanics, drivers, miners, and so on. For example, in 1938, when the French SNCF was formed, it employed 500,000 people for 43,000 km of track.)

Comment: +1 to AlexP. There is no way to keep everything else ancient. At best, we can get a "steampunk world with no gunpowder".

Comment: AlexP has it right.  Easy access to steel in quantities enough for a rail network requires an Industrial Revolution level of tech plus an equivalent civilization size.  Access to aluminum in large quantities not only implies access to electricity but access to electricity in colossal quantities required for electrolytic extraction of aluminum from ore.

Comment: @AlexP These aren't regular trains, they are 1800 to 1850 level trains, its still a massive step up from horses, but its still effectively just a single steam engine on some wheels, not even really a cabin on it. SNCF was formed in the era where you were starting to see diesel & electric locomotives running

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan I got rid of the aluminium from this. Also steel was being produced using a method similar to today in at least back to the 11th century in china in a similar method to the first European mass steel producing method..

Comment: You might want to get rid of "reliable radios", too. That would require science and a tech pyramid that you really can't sweep under the rug. I'd argue that the Romans còuld have built a railway using their known tech & engineering prowess. Radios, not so much.

Comment: I am not sure why you would believe that running a railway in 1850 needed less people than in 1930. It didn't. And you must add the people who dig out the iron ore and the coal, the people who build the engines and the cars, and so on. *Technology is a pyramid*, you cannot have the capstone without the lower courses.

Comment: See [*I, Pencil*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/I,_Pencil) by [Leonard E. Read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Read) for a short and gentle introduction. Very highly recommended. (The link goes to Wikimedia.)

Comment: @AlexP because the trains are smaller & far *far* simpler

Comment: Trains are smaller and just a little bit simpler... But the technological support is vastly less developed. There are no automated signals, no track blocks, no centralized switching, and so on. For example, you literally have men every few miles of track keeping track of passing trains; two men per post, three shifts per day. Railways really employed *an army* of men before the middle of the 20th century. In Europe they even wore uniforms.

Comment: Forget warfare, the presence of early generation radios and railways will change the entire world to be no longer recognisable as "Caesar era"

Answer (score 3):

### Like the American Civil War, with no gunpowder

The American Civil War is the first large scale conflict with a good, documented prevalence of [railroad as transport](https://americanexperience.si.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/How-the-Railroad-Won-the-War.pdf), which played a decisive role in defining the winner.

Depending on the geographical features of the conflict, steamboats could also come into play as relevant logistics players

Of course, as most warfare, logistics would play the decisive factor, so the parties will try to sabotage each others' supply lines, so expect railroads to be prime targets (in the linked .pdf there is an example of railroad sabotage that doesn't involve blowing the tracks up)

Since steel and aluminum are accessible and depending on their level of metalworking, you can certainly expect fortified carts / rudimentary cars and more prevalence of [siege weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_siege_engines) as they'll be lighter and easier to assemble and transport

Comment: No gunpowder seems extremely unlikely when you've managed to make a radio, even a primitive one.  Gunpowder is really easy to invent compared to radio - it's almost impossible to avoid accidentally discovering gunpowder well before you discover radio.  Voted up anyway.